# Library package helps interact with Blockchain on the Ethereum platform (ETH, BSC, Polygon...) more simple and minimized

Tags: web3js, events, ethereumjs, raw-transaction, smart-contract

I am a Blockchain engineer and after 3 years of working with the EVM-platform I used many different libraries such as **web3, ethers, ethereumjs-tx,...** I realized they are so distributed and complex to use for newbies.

So now, I am developing a new npm package to sum up and minimize all of above packages to support interaction with Ethereum Smart-contract **(write-read function)**, and also supply more related utils **(sign, recover, encode, decode,...)** on Blockchain networks running EVM **(Ethereum, Binance, Polygon,..)**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-blockchain-helper

`npm install eth-blockchain-helper --save`

I hope this is helpful to you. Using and please give me feedback, and also new features that you want to be added to this package.

Many thanks and have a nice day!!